# Error is calling a function a property AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

> C:...\HandleXML.as, Line 28   1120: Access of undefined property processXML.

Why?... This is not my Document class, but there is nothing calling on this class in it. It worked when I had it in my document class, but I'm trying to split the document class up into multiple classes. No matter what I read, having multiple classes is still weird for me.

```
package  {

    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
    import flash.xml.*;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.net.URLLoader;
    import flash.net.FileReference;
    import flash.net.FileFilter;

    public class HandleXML {

        public static var mapXML:XML;
        public var saveXML:XML;
        public var file:FileReference; 
        public var fileLoader:URLLoader;
        public var saveFile:FileReference; 

        public function HandleXML() 
        {
            // constructor code
        }
        public static function UseGeneric()
        {
            var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
            myLoader.load(new URLRequest("Maps/TestMap.xml"));
            myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXML);
        }

        public function loadFileDialogue():void 
        { 
            file =  new FileReference();   
            var xmlFileTypes:FileFilter =  new FileFilter("XML (Maps/*.xml)",  "Maps/*.xml;");   
            file.browse();
            file.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, selectFile);
        }

        public function selectFile(e:Event):void 
        { 
            file.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadFile); 
            file.load();
        }

        function loadFile(e:Event):void 
        { 
            fileLoader =  new URLLoader();
            fileLoader.load(new URLRequest("Maps/"+file.name));
            fileLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXML);
        }

        public function processXML(e:Event)
        {
            mapXML = new XML(e.target.data);
            ParseIntoArray();
        }

        public function SaveFile():void
        {
            BuildSaveXML();
            saveFile = new FileReference(); 
            saveFile.save((saveXML), "SavedXML.xml");
        }

        public function BuildSaveXML()
        {
            var xmlOutput:String =  "<Map>" + 
                                    "<MapWidth>" + mapXML.MapWidth + "</MapWidth>" +
                                    "<MapHeight>" + mapXML.MapHeight + "</MapHeight>" +
                                    "<ROW>" + Engine.mapArray.toString()+"</ROW>" + 
                                    "</Map>";

            saveXML = new XML(xmlOutput);
        }

        public function ParseIntoArray()
        {
            var tempArray:Array = new Array();
            var tempStr:String = mapXML.ROW.toString();

            tempStr = tempStr.replace(/<ROW>/g, "");
            tempStr = tempStr.replace(/<\/ROW>/g, "");

            tempArray.push(tempStr.split(","));

            for(var i:int = 0; i < mapXML.MapHeight; i++)
            {
                Engine.mapArray[i] = [];

                for(var j:int = 0; j < mapXML.MapWidth; j++)
                {
                    Engine.mapArray[i].push(tempArray[0].shift());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you pointed out, the `UseGeneric` function is declared to be static when it shouldn't be:

```
public function UseGeneric()
{
    var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    myLoader.load(new URLRequest("Maps/TestMap.xml"));
    myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXML);
}
```

Comment: I guess I don't understand event listeners very well. I've been using them without problems up until now, though. I thought that it worked like... addEventListener("Event to listen for", function to use once event is heard). I've never thought of functions as variables or properties unless using function get... I know what regular old variables are...

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't noticed it was a function. Try using 'this.processXML' and see if that works.

Comment: C:...HandleXML.as, Line 28 1061: Call to a possibly undefined method addEventListener through a reference with static type HandleXML.

Comment: ahhhh. I think it was because I had public STATIC function UseGeneric... Working fine now. Thank you so much!

Comment: Good job catching that, I didn't notice it since I was going off of the error saying that the `processXML` property was undefined. Glad you were able to fix it. Cheers.

Comment: Another question. Again, new to multiple classes. So, the XML file loads fine. It then parses the info from <ROW /> into the temp array and all that. When I trace(Engine.mapArray); it shows me the array I want. (Engine is my document class btw). mapArray is a public static variable in Engine.as. After I call upon HandleXML.UseGeneric() - runs all the parseintoarray, blablabla - I trace(mapArray) in Engine.as and it shows nothing. Like it's not passing mapArray back to Engine. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you initialize `mapArray`? I don't see it being initialized anywhere in your `HandleXML` class.  Somewhere, you need to have a `mapArray = new Array()` instantiation being done. If that's not being done, say in your Engine class, then that would be a problem; however, an error should have been thrown if that happened.

Comment: public static var mapArray:Array = []; as I understand is the same as new Array();

Comment: Hmmm, if you haven't yet, set a breakpoint at the line of code where you add items to `mapArray` and debug the application (SHIFT+CMD+ENTER) so that you can step through each iteration to see what is going on. If your breakpoint is never hit, then you know that it is never adding anything to your array.  Debugging by using breakpoints is the fastest way to determine issues of this nature.

Comment: You, sir, are a scholar. It was because I was calling 2 functions from my dropdown list ...
    case "genericMap":   
    handleXML.UseGeneric();  GenerateMap(); 
    break;   and it was trying to GenerateMap() before the array was passed back. How can I make it GenerateMap() directly after ParseIntoArray is done? I'll figure it out... Thanks a lot!

Comment: HAHA! Glad to see you were able to find the issue. Cheers.